# Shortened "cannot be disabled"

Tags: single-word-requests

How can "cannot be disabled" be written in short form, similar to the way "can be removed" can be written as "removable"?

I didn't find the answer in Google Translate.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to put this as an answer, but I'd probably use your original phrase, or "undisableable", but the second one sounds made up. One might instead say "Permanently Enabled"

Comment: You need to provide more context. Clearly you're not referring to anything like an *option* (the kind of thing that we usually speak of "enabling/disabling"). About the only "generic" things I can think of that can't be disabled are *gravity* and *time*. What other thing have you got in mind?

Comment: @TecBrat Ha. Yeah, 'undisableable' doesn't really sound like a word ;)  volocuga, I agree with Fumble--give us the sentence you want to use it in, and we can think of a replacement word that will get your meaning across :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

> [***immutable***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/immutable): *unalterable; Not subject or susceptible to change*

That may be a bit more encompassing than you had originally envisioned.

Comment: Yes, "immutable" sounds pretty good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the engineering field the short term can be "always on" (or "always off").